# SQL Server Select only part of String

Tags: sql, sql-server

If someone can help me with selecting only left part of string before '('.

For example I have this string:

```
SS0054(BOSCH)
```

and I want to select only text to the LEFT of the `(`, and ignore the right part.

I have managed to select left part, but in my data I also have string values without `(` in it for example just `SS0054`, but then I get error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the left function

How can I select all values, to the left of `(` in strings where a `(` exists?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(RTRIM(LTRIM('SS0054(BOSCH)')), CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(RTRIM(LTRIM('SS0054(BOSCH)')))) - 1));
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check '(' in your string like this:

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(50)='78BD0920-2(VALEO)'

SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('(',@string)!=0
THEN 
UPPER(LEFT(RTRIM(LTRIM(@string)), CHARINDEX('(', @string) - 1))
 ELSE @string -- ( not exist
  end
```

Comment: What about string like string mentioned below: 78BD0920-2(VALEO), it only selects 78BD09 Not All characters Left from (

Answer (score 2):

Use a CASE statement, and you can simplify your original code to find the text before the '('.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('(', MY_STR) <> 0 THEN
        UPPER(SUBSTRING(MY_STR, 0, CHARINDEX('(', MY_STR)))
    ELSE
        UPPER(MY_STR) -- or whatever else you wish to display
    END
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you always want the first 6 characters. Will substring work?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('SS0054(BOSCH)', 0,7) AS partString;
```

You can add the LTRIM, RTRIM if you require

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM(' SS0054(BOSCH) ' )), 0,7) AS partString;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering, the string were just examples, I have other strings and longer like: 78BD0920-2(VALEO), it won't work substring...